# Using 'new' to allocate memory dynamically in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

I am working on some C++ code and am having some problems with the function described below. I haven't used much C++ before, at least not for a long time and so i'm trying to learn as I go along to a large extent. The win32api doesn't help much with the confusion factor either...

The function is succesfully called twice, before failing when called at a later stage when it is called in the application.

```
PTSTR getDomainFromDN(PTSTR dnPtstr) {

size_t nDn=wcslen(dnPtstr);
size_t *pnNumCharConverted = new size_t;

wchar_t *szTemp = new wchar_t[10];          // for debugging purposes
_itow_s((int)nDn,szTemp,10,10);             // for debugging purposes

AddToMessageLog(EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,szTemp);        // for debugging purposes (displays an integer value before failing)
AddToMessageLog(EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,TEXT("Marker A"));  // for debugging purposes
char *dn = new char[nDn];
    // !!!!!!!!!!!! all goes wrong here, doesn't get to next line, nDn does have a value when it fails (61)
AddToMessageLog(EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,TEXT("Marker B"));  // for debugging purposes

wcstombs_s(pnNumCharConverted,dn,nDn+1,dnPtstr,nDn+1);

...more code here...

delete[] dn;
delete pnNumCharConverted;

return result
}
```

At first i thought it was a memory allocation problem or something as it fails on the line `char *dn = new char[nDn];`, the last marker showing as 'Marker A'. I used `delete[]` on the pointer further down to no avail. I know that `nDn` is a value because I print this out to a message log using `_itow_s` for debugging. I also know that `dnPtrstr` is a PTSTR.

I tried using `malloc` as well with `free()` in the old C style but this doesn't improve things.

Comment: It is tricky once you start fiddling with pointers like that

Comment: `size_t *pnNumCharConverted = new size_t;`  Oh my.

Comment: You're using too much of `new`.

Comment: Are both your RAM memory and HDD completely full? **And don't say my favorite language has an old style!** :)

Comment: No, but now you mention it, the CPU is pretty much through the roof! @Nawaz, what can i use instead of new? perhaps i'm missing something more fundamental?

Comment: @user723459: Yes. Why dont you simply write `size_t NumCharConverted;`? What is the point of using `new` even here?

Comment: @user723459: In C++ you can define local variables on the stack.  Instead of `size_t *pnNumCharConverted = new size_t;`, just write `size_t numCharConverted`, and use it.  BTW, you might want to check out the book "Accelerated C++" by Koenig and Moo.

Comment: `nDn`? Really? You know, the language doesn't prohibit you from using meaningful variable names. Also, most languages are tricky when you don't understand them, and are trying to guess how they work. Might I suggest actually spending a bit of time *learning* the basics of the language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried sanitizing your code a bit. One of the big tricks to C++ is to *not explicitly use memory management when it can be avoided*. Use vectors instead of raw arrays. Strings instead of char pointers.

And don't unnecessarily allocate objects dynamically. Put them on the stack, where they're automatically freed.

And, as in every other language, *initialize your variables*.

```
PTSTR getDomainFromDN(PTSTR dnPtstr) {
    std::wstring someUnknownString = dnPtstr;

    size_t numCharConverted = 0;

    std::wstring temp; // for debugging purposes
    std::ostringstream sstr;
    sstr << temp;
    AddToMessageLog(EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,sstr.str().c_str());        // for debugging purposes (displays an integer value before failing)

    AddToMessageLog(EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,TEXT("Marker A"));  // for debugging purposes
    std::vector<char> dn(someUnknownString.size());

    AddToMessageLog(EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,TEXT("Marker B"));  // for debugging purposes

    wcstombs_s(&numCharConverted, &dn[0], dn.size(), someUnknownString.c_str(), dn.size());

    ...more code here...

    return result
}
```

This might not have solved your problem, but it has eliminated a large number of potential errors.
Given that I can't reproduce your problem from the code you've supplied, this is really the best I can do.

Now, if you could come up with sane names instead of `dnPtstr` and `dn`, it might actually be nearly readable. ;)

Comment: "And, as in every other language, initialize your variables." Every language that isn't recently developed? :)

Comment: @GMan Back in my day, we didn't even have variables! We just had registers, and we were glad to have them!

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is this line:

`wcstombs_s(pnNumCharConverted,dn,nDn+1,dnPtstr,nDn+1);`

because you are telling wcstombs_s to copy up to nDn+1 characters into dn which is only nDn characters long.

try changing the line to:

`wcstombs_s(pnNumCharConverted,dn,nDn,dnPtstr,nDn);`

or perhaps better yet:

`wcstombs_s(pnNumCharConverted,dn,nDn,dnPtstr,_TRUNCATE);`

im not sure how you are debugging this or how AddToMessageLog is implemented, but if you are just inspecting the log to trace the code, and AddToMessageLog is buffering your logging, then perhaps the error occurs before that buffer is flushed.

Comment: yeah, i think i did this because i thought it accounted for the null terminator at the end of the string. Although the code doesn't fail there, it fails in between marker A and B which point to that one line `char *dn = new char[nDn];`. I treid this function out as it's own small program and it seemed to work fine there. It works fine in this app for the first two times and then goes wrong later when it is called. Just tried what you said and it doesn't work but thanks anyway

Comment: @user723459 you might need to post the code that lives at "...more code here...", also it might help to see where you call this function, and where you create the dnPtstr and what you do with the result of the function.

Comment: @user723459 Writing beyond the end of an allocated block (typically) won't cause the program to fail immediately, but it will often corrupt the free space arena, which will cause problems in some future `new` or `delete`.

Comment: @user723459 @James Kanze exactly, which is why its crashing after the 2nd or 3rd run, and hence why i think the code that plays with all these pointers needs to be posted, because i wouldnt be surprised if there is some dodgy pointer usage happening elsewhere too.

Comment: @James Kanze I have since 'solved' the issue by doin it another way altogether! I might try to get hold of the code i had and post it up here but i haven't got it to hand. It would be nice to know what was causing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that "char *dn = new char[nDn];" is failing, TRY "set_new_handler" -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fath9te(VS.80).aspx

On a side note, few things:

1. The very first operation "size_t nDn=wcslen(dnPtstr);" is not 100% correct. **You are doing wcslen on dnPtstr assuming dnPtstr to be unicode. However, this is not the case since it could be PWSTR or PSTR based on whether UNICODE is defined or not.** So, use _tcslen(). Its better if you give some time to understand UNICODE, NON-UNICODE stuff since they would help you a lot in Windows C++ development.
2. Why are you using so many "new" if you are using these variables only in this function (I am assuming it). **Prefer stack over heap for local variables unles you have a definite requirement.**

Comment: i'll look into this, thanks. Does anyone have any recommendations for a good c++ book that will set me straight on all this as i feel like i need get some fundamentals under my belt. ta

Comment: how would i redo the line `char *dn = new char[nDn];` without using 'new'?

Comment: char dn[MAX_SIZE] = {0}; // define MAX_SIZE to something that can hold Dn. Infact, since you are using WindowsAPIs, better use TCHAR dn[MAX_SIZE] = {0};

Comment: I thought that declaring it as an array, rather than with new,  meant that the MAX_SIZE value must be known at compile time? `nDn` is not known until the code is run. Is this correct?